# Convert sheet to Django objects without explicit column names

Tags: django, excel, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

The current application that I have parses sheet data row by row and creates a Django object for each row based on a specified set of column names.

The next step would be to extend the application to work without column names explicitly specified in Django model. The data (**both names + values have to be stored**) can be stored either as explicit attributes or in a data structure with key->value mapping. The class methods will be used to classify the data based on a learning algorithm.

How can the same thing be done without knowing the column names in advance?

models.py:

```
class Samplemodel(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    Phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    Other = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

serializers.py

```
class SamplemodelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Samplemodel
        fields = ('Name', 'Phone', 'Email', 'Other')
```

models-generic.py:

```
class Genericmodel(models.Model):
    c1name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    c2name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    c3name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    c4name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

serializers-generic.py:

```
class GenericSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Samplemodel
        fields = ('c1name', 'c2name', 'c3name', 'c4name', ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get why you need 2 models?

Input your unknown value to your classifier. Some how you get your 4 class probabilities (name, phone, etc.). Use the biggest probability to tag your unknown value. Repeat the process for the others, then save the original model. You might need to have some rules to resolve ambiguities.

Comment: First of all, I don't need 2 models. The first one is the current model that I have now and the second is the same model how it should be after the changes so that it can be filled with generic data.